# Error: unexpected '}' in "}". How do I transform working code into a function?

Tags: r, function

I have developed code that requires simple input values and the output is a plot.

```
library(spatstat)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)


dim <- 2000
radiusCluster<-100
lambdaParent<-.02
lambdaDaughter<-30
hosts<-900
randmod<-0

numbparents<-rpois(1,lambdaParent*dim)

xxParent<-runif(numbparents,0+radiusCluster,dim-radiusCluster)
yyParent<-runif(numbparents,0+radiusCluster,dim-radiusCluster)

numbdaughter<-rpois(numbparents,(lambdaDaughter))
sumdaughter<-sum(numbdaughter)

theta<-2*pi*runif(sumdaughter)
rho<-radiusCluster*sqrt(runif(sumdaughter))

xx0=rho*cos(theta)
yy0=rho*sin(theta)

xx<-rep(xxParent,numbdaughter)
yy<-rep(yyParent,numbdaughter)

xx<-xx+xx0

yy<-yy+yy0
cds<-data.frame(xx,yy)
is_outlier<-function(x){
  x > dim| x < 0
}
cds<-cds[!(is_outlier(cds$xx)|is_outlier(cds$yy)),]
sampleselect<-sample(1:nrow(cds),hosts,replace=F)
cds<-cds%>%slice(sampleselect)

randfunction<-function(x){
  x<-runif(length(x),0,dim)
}
randselect<-sample(1:nrow(cds),floor(hosts*randmod),replace=F)
cds[randselect,]<-apply(cds[randselect,],1,randfunction)
landscape<-ppp(x=cds$xx,y=cds$yy,window=owin(xrange=c(0,dim),yrange=c(0,dim)))
ggplot(data.frame(landscape))+geom_point(aes(x=x,y=y))+coord_equal()+theme_minimal()
```

I need to run this code for multiple parameters so I need to transform the parameter inputs into a function. I tried creating a function of the above code like this.

```
cluster_function<-(dim,
                   lambdaParent,
                   lambdaDaughter,
                   hosts,
                   randmod,
                   radiusCluster){
numbparents<-rpois(1,lambdaParent*dim)

xxParent<-runif(numbparents,0+radiusCluster,dim-radiusCluster)
yyParent<-runif(numbparents,0+radiusCluster,dim-radiusCluster)

numbdaughter<-rpois(numbparents,(lambdaDaughter))
sumdaughter<-sum(numbdaughter)

theta<-2*pi*runif(sumdaughter)
rho<-radiusCluster*sqrt(runif(sumdaughter))

xx0=rho*cos(theta)
yy0=rho*sin(theta)

xx<-rep(xxParent,numbdaughter)
yy<-rep(yyParent,numbdaughter)

xx<-xx+xx0

yy<-yy+yy0
cds<-data.frame(xx,yy)
is_outlier<-function(x){
  x > dim| x < 0
}
cds<-cds[!(is_outlier(cds$xx)|is_outlier(cds$yy)),]
sampleselect<-sample(1:nrow(cds),hosts,replace=F)
cds<-cds%>%slice(sampleselect)

randfunction<-function(x){
  x<-runif(length(x),0,dim)
}
randselect<-sample(1:nrow(cds),floor(hosts*randmod),replace=F)
cds[randselect,]<-apply(cds[randselect,],1,randfunction)
}
```

However this returns the error "Error: unexpected '}' in "}". How can I correct this error?

Comment: Check your `(`, `)`, `{`, and `}` carefully. There is either a mistake somewhere, or you have partially ran the code. Seems like there is an extra `}` somewhere.

Comment: Actually, it looks like you forgot `function` in the first line. `cluster_function <- function(...)`

Comment: RStudio's automatic indentation and code formatting can help find errors like this. If you're using RStudio, select all the code and in the menu go to Code > Reformat Code.